# Add /home partition space into / partition Fedora 20

Tags: linux, fedora

I am using Fedora 20 and I have 10 GB for my / (root) partition. I am currently running out of space on this partition. My /home partition has almost 60 GB free space.

I need to use the root partition for my work. How can I add that extra 60 GB space from /home partition to my root partition?

Comment: Which partitioning scheme have you used when installing Fedora? Are you using LVM?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a live Linux distro (*i.e.*, something on a CD or USB stick); insert it, reboot into the live, choose (if you are asked) *Try Ubuntu/Debian... without installing*, and then install *GParted*. Start it, from the live, as sudo, select your /home partition, and choose *resize*.  Select the new size, then go see a movie with your girlfriend (= it will take some time).

When it is done, it is most likely that the newly freed space is not immediately adjacent to the root partition. If it is immediately adjacent, perfect, click on the root partition and expand it. If, as I suspect, it is not, then you cannot just expand the root partition to include the newly freed space: you will have instead to use it at another mountpoint.

I suggest you use /usr, which is typically the largest subdirectory inside root, except for /home, of course. If for any reason some other subdir of yours is larger than /usr (for instance, if you are running a Web sevrer off this particular machine, /var is likely to be larger), then choose this largest subdir as the mountpoint for the newly created free partition.

Careful, though: you cannot immediately mount as, say, /usr, because for the moment you already have a /usr subdir. So, initially, call the new mountpoint /new.

Reboot into Fedora, and copy the contents of /usr (or var, or whatever) into /new, with the command:

```
 cp  -pR /usr /new
```

(-p preserves permissions, -R copies recursively all directories inside /usr).

Check that everything went well, rename /usr as, say, /usr-old, change /etc/fstab to mount the new partition at mountpoint /usr instead of /new, reboot, you are done. Now, if everything works fine, you can empty /usr-old, which will appear as free room for the rest of the /root partition.

Last, but not least: *60GB* to add to /root are definitely too many. Furthermore, you would be left without room for /home. *10-15GB* should be plenty.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot to a livecd, move /usr to /home/.usr, and create a symlink from /home/.usr to /usr. No doubt /usr is consuming most of the space on that 10GB partition. This works fine - I do this with /opt regularly.